# How to achieve or get Post script (PS) output from xelatex run?

Tags: xetex

Does this require any sort of switches while running XeLaTeX?

Comment: Uh I found it in xelatex --help. The option switch is -no-pdf.

Comment: `--no-pdf` gives `xdv` (an extended `dvi`). I don't know a driver to get ps from there. dvips will have problems with the fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you get the PDF output, you can use `pdftops` or GhostScript (gs) to get the PostScript file. For example:

```
xelatex foo.tex
pdftops foo.pdf foo.ps
```

PS: `-no-pdf` option is not for PostScript output.